# Sequelize: How to Select in two tables with no relations?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have three tables, Company, Permissions and CompanyPermissions(relations), I need to know which permissions are not registered in CompanyPermissionsand which are the companies.
Example

| Company |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |

| Permissions |
| --- |
| 3 |
| 4 |

CompanyPermission

| Company | Permission |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |

I need select All Permissions and All Companies no have records ins CompanyPermission. Example:

| Company | Permission |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |

In select raw i achieved this with

SELECT
"Permission"."id" as "Permission.id",
"Company"."id" as "Company.id",
"CompanyPermissions"."id"
from "Permission"
join "Company" on 1=1
left join "CompanyPermissions"  on "CompanyPermissions"."permissao_id" ="Permission"."id" and "Company"."id"="CompanyPermissions".empresa_id
where "CompanyPermissions"."id" is null

How to do this with findAll and includes.... ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Path:
Server side => src => app => models => companyPermissions.js

Include this code:

```
static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.Permission, { foreignKey: 'id', as: 'Permission'})
    this.belongsTo(models.Company, { foreignKey: 'id', as: 'Company'})
  }
```

Then create a CompanyPermissionController

Path:
Server side => src => app => controllers => CompanyPermissionController.js

```
import CompanyPermission from '../models/CompanyPermission';
import Company from '../models/Company';
import Permission from '../models/Permission';

class CompanyPermissionController {

  async index(req, res) {

    const url = 'your URL'

    const permissions = await CompanyPermission.findAndCountAll({
      include: [
        {
          model: Permission,
          as: 'Permission'
        },
        {
          model: Company,
          as: 'Company'
        }
      ]
    })

    return res.json({
      count: permissions.count,
      rows: permissions.rows,
      method: {
        type: 'GET',
        url: `${url}/PARAMETERS`,
      }
    })
  }
}

export default new CompanyPermissionController();
```

Comment: Tnks, but i want only the records don't exists in companypermissions, i need insert this... my models already exists with the relations with belongs...

Comment: Sorry i missed the most important part. Anyway you can't select the data you don't have on SQL or maybe this query would be a lot complex. I would suggest to do in your backend, combining the results and returning the data you want. -- Maybe create an array of objects that keys as companies and values as companypermissions and then compare with missed permissions.

Comment: Tnks, i achieved this goal using query raw, but in my opinion losting the sense of use ORM, but for now i resolved this problem in this way